# No funciona calculadora con javascript otra vez

Tags: php, javascript

ya es la tercera pregunta pero ya que, la calculadora solo lanza el resultado de la operacion de suma, lo que es resta, multiplicacion y division no, la verdad ya no se que puede ser, les agradeceria mucho su ayuda.

```js
function operaciones($sumar,$restar,$multi,$divi) 
{
  if ($sumar == "1") 
  {
   var caja1 = document.getElementById("caja1").value;
   var caja2 = document.getElementById("caja2").value;
    var resultado = parseInt(caja1) + parseInt(caja2);
    document.getElementById("result").value = resultado;
  }

  else if ($restar == "2") 
  {
   var caja1 = document.getElementById("caja1").value;
    var caja2 = document.getElementById("caja2").value;
    var resultado = parseInt(caja1) - parseInt(caja2);
    document.getElementById("result").value = resultado;
  }

  else if ($multi == "3") 
  {
   var caja1 = document.getElementById("caja1").value;
    var caja2 = document.getElementById("caja2").value;
   var resultado = parseInt(caja1) * parseInt(caja2);
    document.getElementById("result").value = resultado;
  }

  else if ($divi == "4") 
  {
    var caja1 = document.getElementById("caja1").value;
    var caja2 = document.getElementById("caja2").value;
    var resultado = parseInt(caja1) / parseInt(caja2);
    document.getElementById("result").value = resultado.toFixed(2);
  }

 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Calculadora</title>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="operaciones.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div align="center">
 <h1>Calculadora | Manejador de nodos</h1>
 <br>
 <label>numero 1</label>
 <input type="text" name="caja1" id="caja1">
 <br>
 <br>
 <label>numero 2</label>
 <input type="text" name="caja2" id="caja2">
 <br>
 <br>
 <label>Operación</label>

 <select name="operacion" id="operacion" onchange="operaciones(this.value)">
  <option value="">Seleccione una operacion</option>
  <option value="1">+</option>
  <option value="2">-</option>
  <option value="3">*</option>
  <option value="4">/</option>
 </select>
 <br>
 <br>
 <label>Resultado</label>
 <input type="text" name="resultado" id="result">
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: el único lenguaje donde las variables se inicializan con el signo de `$` es en PHP en los demás es un error, considera eso

Comment: con o sin $ sigue funcionando, el error ya se solucionó, gracias.

Comment: claro que funciona pero no es correcto a nivel sintáctico

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La función está mal diseñada, unicamente debes pasar un valor como parámetro y ese valor compararlo dentro de la funcion para obtener el tipo de operación

Prueba con esto

```
function operaciones($operacion) 
{
        if ($operacion == "1") 
        {
            var caja1 = document.getElementById("caja1").value;
            var caja2 = document.getElementById("caja2").value;
            var resultado = parseInt(caja1) + parseInt(caja2);
            document.getElementById("result").value = resultado;
        }

        if ($operacion == "2") 
        {
            var caja1 = document.getElementById("caja1").value;
            var caja2 = document.getElementById("caja2").value;
            var resultado = parseInt(caja1) - parseInt(caja2);
            document.getElementById("result").value = resultado;
        }

        if ($operacion == "3") 
        {
            var caja1 = document.getElementById("caja1").value;
            var caja2 = document.getElementById("caja2").value;
            var resultado = parseInt(caja1) * parseInt(caja2);
            document.getElementById("result").value = resultado;
        }

        if ($operacion == "4") 
        {
            var caja1 = document.getElementById("caja1").value;
            var caja2 = document.getElementById("caja2").value;
            var resultado = parseInt(caja1) / parseInt(caja2);
            document.getElementById("result").value = resultado.toFixed(2);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Totalmente de acuerdo contigo, aunque en ese caso como solo se esta comparando el contenido de una variable que sea igual a algo, sería buena idea utilizar un switch.

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que no detectaste bien las variables en cuestión en tu definición de requerimientos, lo que estás seleccionando es una operación.

```js
function operaciones($operacion) {
  if ($operacion == "1") {
    var caja1 = document.getElementById("caja1").value;
    var caja2 = document.getElementById("caja2").value;
    var resultado = parseInt(caja1) + parseInt(caja2);
    document.getElementById("result").value = resultado;
  } else if ($operacion == "2") {
    var caja1 = document.getElementById("caja1").value;
    var caja2 = document.getElementById("caja2").value;
    var resultado = parseInt(caja1) - parseInt(caja2);
    document.getElementById("result").value = resultado;
  } else if ($operacion == "3") {
    var caja1 = document.getElementById("caja1").value;
    var caja2 = document.getElementById("caja2").value;
    var resultado = parseInt(caja1) * parseInt(caja2);
    document.getElementById("result").value = resultado;
  } else if ($operacion == "4") {
    var caja1 = document.getElementById("caja1").value;
    var caja2 = document.getElementById("caja2").value;
    var resultado = parseInt(caja1) / parseInt(caja2);
    document.getElementById("result").value = resultado.toFixed(2);
  }

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Calculadora</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="operaciones.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div align="center">
    <h1>Calculadora | Manejador de nodos</h1>
    <br>
    <label>numero 1</label>
    <input type="text" name="caja1" id="caja1">
    <br>
    <br>
    <label>numero 2</label>
    <input type="text" name="caja2" id="caja2">
    <br>
    <br>
    <label>Operación</label>

    <select name="operacion" id="operacion" onchange="operaciones(this.value)">
      <option value="">Seleccione una operacion</option>
      <option value="1">+</option>
      <option value="2">-</option>
      <option value="3">*</option>
      <option value="4">/</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <br>
    <label>Resultado</label>
    <input type="text" name="resultado" id="result">
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Para que no te confundas con muchos ifs te recomiendo usar un switch, te permite trabajar con varios casos posibles de valores que pueda tomar una variable, en tu caso `$operacion`.

```js
function operaciones($operacion) {
  switch ($operacion) {
    case "suma":
      var caja1 = document.getElementById("caja1").value;
      var caja2 = document.getElementById("caja2").value;
      var resultado = parseInt(caja1) + parseInt(caja2);
      document.getElementById("result").value = resultado;
      break;
    case "resta":
      var caja1 = document.getElementById("caja1").value;
      var caja2 = document.getElementById("caja2").value;
      var resultado = parseInt(caja1) - parseInt(caja2);
      document.getElementById("result").value = resultado;
      break;
    case "multiplicacion":
      var caja1 = document.getElementById("caja1").value;
      var caja2 = document.getElementById("caja2").value;
      var resultado = parseInt(caja1) * parseInt(caja2);
      document.getElementById("result").value = resultado;
      break;
    case "division":
      var caja1 = document.getElementById("caja1").value;
      var caja2 = document.getElementById("caja2").value;
      var resultado = parseInt(caja1) / parseInt(caja2);
      document.getElementById("result").value = resultado.toFixed(2);
      break;
    default:
      document.getElementById("result").value = "";
      break;
  }

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Calculadora</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="operaciones.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div align="center">
    <h1>Calculadora | Manejador de nodos</h1>
    <br>
    <label>numero 1</label>
    <input type="text" name="caja1" id="caja1">
    <br>
    <br>
    <label>numero 2</label>
    <input type="text" name="caja2" id="caja2">
    <br>
    <br>
    <label>Operación</label>

    <select name="operacion" id="operacion" onchange="operaciones(this.value)">
      <option value="">Seleccione una operacion</option>
      <option value="suma">+</option>
      <option value="resta">-</option>
      <option value="multiplicacion">*</option>
      <option value="division">/</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <br>
    <label>Resultado</label>
    <input type="text" name="resultado" id="result">
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

cabe destacar en el ejemplo el uso de `default`, que es para todos los casos no contemplados, así en particular si alguien selecciona una operación y después elige de nuevo `Seleccione una operación` se borrará el resultado en vez de dejar el número previamente calculado. A este enfoque de no dejar nada al azar se le conoce como "software a prueba de balas"